# Javascript Calculate Total Inputs With Same Values

Tags: javascript

I would like to know how many different users are in each industry by calculating the number of inputs that return a specific industry. I would like to then print the total results on the page for each industry.

```
while($db_name = mysqli_fetch_row($set)){
echo '<input value="'.$companyindustry.'" name="companyindustry" type="text" />';
}
echo '<p>$companyindustry : (total_number)</p>';
```

Results

```
<input name="Animal & Pet" value="Animal & Pet" />
<input name="Animal & Pet" value="Animal & Pet" />
<input name="Engineering & Energy" value="Engineering & Energy" />

Animal & Pet = (2)
Engineering & Energy = (1)
```

Javascript

```
<script>
function countIndustryType(){
    var arr = document.querySelectorAll('input[value=$companyindustry]');
    var total=0;
    arr.forEach(function(item){

    });

}
countIndustryType();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to assign each input element a specific class so that you can select specific inputs required.

```
var arr = {};
var els = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for(var i = 0;i < els.length;i++) {
    if(arr[els[i].name]) {
        arr[els[i].name] += 1; 
    } else {
        arr[els[i].name] = 1;
    }
}
// Now just iterate over the keys and print the values
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but please no jquery.

Comment: Removed jquery. Currently, I have answered based on what you have. The code will change if you have specific class assigned.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var industry_list = ['Animal & Pet','Engineering & Energy']
var industry_count_obj  = {};
function countIndustryType(){
    industry_list.forEach(function(industry){
            var arr = document.querySelectorAll('input[value="'+industry+'"]');
            var total=0;
            industry_count_obj[industry] = arr.length; 
    })
    console.log(industry_count_obj)
}
countIndustryType();
```

```html
<input name="Animal & Pet" value="Animal & Pet" />
<input name="Animal & Pet" value="Animal & Pet" />
<input name="Engineering & Energy" value="Engineering & Energy" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of all the inputs on the page and then group them by name to get the count for each industry:

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');

const inputsCount = {};

inputs.forEach(i => {
  const name = i.name;
  inputsCount[name] = inputsCount[name] ?
      inputsCount[name] + 1 :
      1;
});

console.log(inputsCount);
```

```html
<input name="Animal & Pet" value="Animal & Pet" />
<input name="Animal & Pet" value="Animal & Pet" />
<input name="Engineering & Energy" value="Engineering & Energy" />
```

Comment: hey looks good but I have a second script that calculates pricing with input value so could you querySelectorAll by tagname or something more specific?

Comment: based on your code there is nothing more specific, the input tag is the common denominator

Comment: In the code I'm trying to select by input value name like this `document.querySelectorAll('input[value=$companyindustry]');`

Comment: Do you have access to the list of companies from JavaScript ? How do you know what `$companyindustry` should be ?

Comment: This happens on the server. You need the list on the client to be able to query input directly based on their names

Answer (score 0):

```
    var obj = {}
    var repeats = [];
    var vlen = document.querySelectorAll('input');

    for (x = 0; x < vlen.length; x++) {
        var l = vlen[x].value;
        obj[l] = (isNaN(obj[l]) ? 1 : obj[l] + 1);
    }
    console.log(obj)
```